# change the font of a sentence in latex to Calligra

Tags: fonts

How can I change the font of a specific sentence in LaTeX to Calligra. I don't want the whole document to be affected. Only a particular sentence.

I checked different fonts from here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html

Then tried different commands (like below), but none of them worked.

```
{\fontfamily{Calligra}\selectfont the font is temporarily changed}
```

It seems that latex can not find the Calligra font.

Comment: Related question: [How do I use a particular font for for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/2693).

Comment: that question doesn't help here ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the documentation of the `calligra` package at http://ctan.org/pkg/calligra, try this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Fee, fi, fo, fum.
{\calligra Foo bar bas; quux!}
\end{document}
```

Note that loading the package enables the `\calligra` command to change the font. The package also provides the `\textcalligra{}` command to set runs of text in that font. Either option is more convenient than loading the font yourself.

If you *want* to load the font yourself however, try `\fontfamily{calligra}`, with the font name in lowercase. (Take a look at how the package loads the font for an example; or see Herbert’s answer for details.)

If these don't work, then perhaps the font package is not installed. It is available under both MiKTeX and TeX Live; see your distribution’s instructions for installing packages.

Answer (score 6):

without loading the package you have to define the font family and shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{calligra}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[1.44]callig15}{}
\begin{document}
foo
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{calligra}\selectfont the font is temporarily changed}
bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Loading the package `calligra` makes more sense (see other answer) and you have also the command `\textcalligra{...}`